# How to detect a hung thread?

Tags: multithreading

Is it possible to detect a hung thread? This thread is not part of any thread pool, its just a system thread. Since thread is hung, it may not process any events.

Thanks,

Comment: What platform?  I think we need more details.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, it is [impossible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_Problem). If you are on Windows and suspect that the thread might be deadlocked, I guess you could use GetThreadContext a few times and check if it is always the same, but I don't know how reliable it will be.

Comment: The proposed solution will only catch very few of the possibilities that a thread might appear "hung". It might catch deadlocks, but it will not catch livelocks.

Answer (score 1):

Not in theory, but in practice it may be possible, depending on your workload. For example if it is supposed to respond to events, you could post a thread message (in windows) and see if it responds. You could set an event or flag that would cause it to do something - you then have to wait for a "reasonable" amount of time to see if it has responded. The question then arises what you would do with the "hung" thread, even if it has really hung and isn't just taking a long time to respond. The thread cannot generally safely be killed and you cannot generally interrupt an arbitrary thread. It is safe enough to log a message to the effect, but who will care? Probably the best thing to do is to note it and figure out the bug that is causing it to hang.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the workload and the kinds of processing done and other details, it may be possible to detect a hung thread.  In some cases, modern VMs can detect a lock deadlock where two threads are hung waiting for the other to release a lock.  (But don't rely on this, because it isn't always possible, only sometimes.)

We need a lot more information before we can give a specific answer to your question.